# HSL color adjustment filter in an iOS 8.0+ app using CoreImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opengl-es, core-image

We want to implement an `HSL` color adjustment filter in an `iOS 8.0+` app using `CoreImage`.

After loading an image, the user selects a color (like red), and then is able to adjust the **hue**, **saturation**, and **luminance** of only that color within the image.  This filter may be applied many times in a second while showing a preview, so performance is extremely important.

The filter should accept parameters of inputImage, target color, and then adjustments of **hue**, **saturation**, and **luminance**.

[image: UI example]

```
CIImage *inputImage
UIColor *targetColor
float hueAdjustment (identity 0)
float saturationAdjustment (identity 0)
float luminanceAdjustment (identity 0)
```

We already tried this method, and since this applies `HSB` filters to whole image and not certain colors, we cannot use this
[How to apply HSB color filters to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168297/how-to-apply-hsb-color-filters-to-uiimage)

I have a feeling that this involves `CIColorMatrix`, but I’m not sure how we would only make the matrix apply to a specific color range.

Comment: Idiotic as it will sound, what's your definition of "a colour"? If I select the colour red — (1.0, 0.0, 0.0) — and map it to blue then what should happen to pixels in my source image that are e.g. (0.99, 0.0, 0.0)? Untouched for being a different colour numerically, adjusted exactly as if pure red by virtue of being close enough, adjusted by some proportional amount related to how close to red it is, or something else?

Comment: It’s not idiotic at all.  It should be color adjusted by some proportional amount, as you said.  The proportion itself could be set as a “tolerance” or some other variable, possibly with a tolerance per color being adjusted, or by some other similar method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: Completed filter (in Swift) is [available here](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia/blob/master/Filterpedia/customFilters/MultiBandHSV.swift)!**

OK, how about another approach then. You could apply individual treatments to each band with a Core Image color kernel which would include code along the lines of:

```
kernel vec4 rgbChannelCompositing(__sample pixel, vec3 hsl0, vec3 hsl1, [...])
{
    float hue = rgb2hsv(pixel).x; // there are lots of rgb2hsv() on the internet :)

    if (hue < color1)
    {
        return treatment(pixel, hsl0); 
    }
    else if (hue >= color1 && hue < color2)
    {
        return treatment(pixel, hsl1);
    }
    [...]
```

The `treatment()` function will do the magic based on the hue, saturation and luminance values passed into the kernel function. This could be as simple as tweaking the HSV values, converting them back to RGB with one of the many `hsv2rgb()` implementations on the internet and returning that.

You may get some banding, in which case a `smoothstep()` will help. I've done something similar to create a pseudo-color filter. In my case, I'm defining the bands based on luminosity rather than color, but the fundamental approach is the same (I think!).

Take a look at `PseudoColor` in my [CustomFilters.swift](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia/blob/master/Filterpedia/customFilters/CustomFilters.swift) file.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a pretty old answer now, but when adjusting the luminance, there's a lot of banding happening. Do you know if there's a way to get rid of some of the banding there? The banding is especially visible on videos.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to have controls simply for red, green and blue, there is a simple solution. I wrote a small `CIColorKernel` that accepts three images and combines them into one by individual channels:

```
kernel vec4 rgbChannelCompositing(__sample red, __sample green, __sample blue)
{
    return vec4(red.r, green.g, blue.b, 1.0);
}
```

This means that you can apply three CI filter chains controlling hue (`CIHueAdjust`), saturation and luminance (`CIColorControls`) to your single image and combine them with my kernel.

It so happens, I've done something along those lines - you can see my Swift code here: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia/blob/master/Filterpedia/customFilters/RGBChannelCompositing.swift

Hope that helps!

Simon

Comment: Thanks!  This could be helpful, but we’re working with 8 specific colors like (0.27, 0.90, 0.27) rather than just RGB, so do you have any idea how to adjust this to work with arbitrary colors?